# how to solve error 127 when installing laravel/ui package?

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-7, laravel-artisan, laravel-ui

I am trying to install laravel/ui package using composer and I am facing this error:

```
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 127
```

I tried to add this line to the composer.json file:

```
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
          "laravel/ui",
        ]
    }
},
```

But it is not working

Comment: Welcome to SO. What were the steps you did to run this error? Did you run composer require ..., php artisan ... ?